# Как создать свойство "изменение переменной"?

Tags: c#

У меня есть переменная X, и я хочу, чтобы когда в Form2 эта переменная меняется, в Form1 сразу же менялся размер кнопок. Как я могу это осуществить?

Comment: Данная переменная создавалась в контексте form2 или form1?

Comment: можно создать таймер на 1 форме для проверки значения переменной Х

Comment: Используйте события

Comment: @Acinit Данная переменная глобальная и создавалась в классе

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Эту переменную нужно создать как свойство и в методе set свойства вызывать событые. Form1 должна подписаться на это событие. Как только значение переменной будет меняться, будет происходит соотвествующее событие, и вызываться все обработчики, которые подписаны на это событие.

Вот простой пример, который демонcтрирует эту технику:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace VariableTrackingDemo {
    static class Globals {
        public static EventHandler VarToTrack_Changed;
        static int val;
        public static int VarToTrack {
            get { return val; }
            set {
                val = value;
                // в C# 5.0 "?." нет, поэтому просто проверяем на
                // не нуль, это же хорошая мысль
                if (VarToTrack_Changed != null) VarToTrack_Changed(val, new EventArgs());
            }
        }
    }
    class VariableTracking {
        // это обработчик события, который делает что-то нужное
        // обработчиков может быть много в разных местах
        static void evhndlr(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            Console.WriteLine(sender.ToString());
        }
        static void Main() {
            // здесь обработчик подписывается на нужное событие
            Globals.VarToTrack_Changed += evhndlr;
            // Globals.VarToTrack_Changed += evhndlr1; ещё один подписали, если нужно
            string s;
            while ((s = Console.ReadLine()) != "") Globals.VarToTrack = Convert.ToInt32(s);
            // в форме и других нестатических объектах нужно удалять подписку
            Globals.VarToTrack_Changed -= evhndlr;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вот это как раз то, что я обычно находил по этому запросу, но как именно вызвать событие в методе set, и как подписать форму на это события я так и не смог разобраться.

Comment: Можно ещё, пожалуйста оставить комментарии после каждой строчки, чтоб я мог разобраться что за что отвечает

Comment: Добавил пример. "void evhndlr ..." и "Globals.VarToTrack_Changed += evhndlr;" будет у вас в Form1. В evhndlr запрограммируйте изменение размеров кнопок, как вам нужно. "Globals.VarToTrack = ..." у вас в Form2 (может находится в любом месте).

Comment: 1. Зачем изобретать велосипед, если есть `INotifyPropertyChanged`? 2. Статика в проекте зло, ее как можно меньше стоит использовать! 3. Форматирование ужасно, именование ужасно... 4. Событие вызывать лучше так: `VarToTrack_Changed?.Invoke(...);`, ибо в вашем случае могут быть ошибки, когда нет подписчиков. 5. `Convert.ToInt32()` многие уже давно не используют, лучше использовать `.Parse()` методы (`int.Parse(...)` или `int.TryParse(...)`). 6. `Console.ReadLine()` в WinForms.... Только запутываете человека. 7. `Console.WriteLine(sender.ToString());` - в строку лишнее, `WriteLine` принимает все.

Comment: Я нашел как это сделать по другому, просто создаю глобальный список кнопок и в форме 2 меняю их свойства. Ответ я всё же приму, т.к у меня он тоже заработал, просто так сложнее.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Огого 1. Много чего есть, а это простой пример. 2. Это кто сказал? Нужна статика - используй, а не думай, что кто-то "злом" обзовёт. 3. На вкус и на цвет товарищей нет. 4. Да, но это не полный учебник. Вставишь лишнее, а потом ещё придётся объяснять, что это и зачем. 5. Многие - это не показатель, и см. п. 1. 6. И где ж ты в примере WinForms увидел? 7. Console.WriteLine неявно вызывает ToString(), а не "принимает все".

Comment: 1. "Как забить гвоздь?" - "Бери камень, привязывай его к палке, действуй", или "Возьми молоток"? В вашем случае вы предлагаете именно создать свой молоток, а не использовать готовый. 2. Сказала практика, тестирование, DI контейнеры, да и вообще индустрия в целом, за подобного в компании вас по головке не погладят. 3. У C# есть как минимум "соглашение об именовании", которому все следуют, вы его нарушаете. Это не дело вкуса. 4. А не вставишь лишнее, потому будут говорить "почему ошибка?". 6. Я вижу его в вопросе. 7. Он принимает все доступные типы (перегрузки), а потом преобразует в строку, да.

Comment: В любом случае я с вами не собираюсь спорить, считаете это нормальным, ваше право. Не забывайте, что вы не один на этом ресурсе, вам этот комментарий кажется бесполезным, другие прислушаются и сделают правильно. Это выбор каждого, как программировать, верно? Я за правильность, вы за топорный стиль, опять-же, ваше право. Ну а так, если вы учитесь, то советую учиться правильным вещам, и тем более правильные вещи должны быть тогда, когда вы учите других (а отвечая на SO вы являетесь в некотором роде учителем). Удачи!

Comment: @EvgeniyZ 1. Ваш способ - это взять вместо молотка какую-нибудь замысловатую хрень, а не просто взять молоток и забить гвоздь, потому что INotifyPropertyChanged тащит много ненужных в данном случае вещей. 2. Что, нужно созадавать единственный в приложении объект вместо использования статического, который создаётся автоматически? В чём вы видите существенную разницу? 3. Про топорный стиль полегче. Как мне нравится, так и пишу. И многие пишут. Мне очень сильно не нравится растянутый на много строк текст, не помогает восприятию. И в VS это опция, настраивается одним чек-боксом.

Comment: 1. INPC это стандартный механизм C#, который используется везде, это также простое событие, только обернутое в интерфейс, который повторю, используют все стандартные механизмы (например привязки обновляют данные при помощи этого события). 2. Да, для этого даже существует "Синглтон" (одиночка). Дойдете до покрытия проекта тестами, использования DI контейнеров, сразу поймете, почему статика зло. 3. Топорный стиль я имею ввиду целиком пример, написанный вами, со статикой, плохим именованием, и др. Ну и как я вам уже сказал, спорить не собираюсь, свое я сказал, прислушиваться или нет, ваше право.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ осталось только побороть static Main :-E

Comment: `Main` это стартовая точка, которая не просто так там сделана статичной. После уже делается обычно полноценный объект приложения, который в этой `Main` точке инициализируется и запускается (посмотрите например в `WinForms`, где в `Main` пишется что-то такое `Application.Run(new Form1());`), некоторые в консольных проектах делают такой финт: `class Program { static void Main() => new Program().Run();  void Run() { ... } }`, тем самым проект становится полноценным, но статика везде, это очень плохо. В виде незначительных "утилит" да, ок, но в остальном, нет, она даже банальное ООП нарушает.

Comment: сегодня вечером наш главный программист, со стажем 20слишним лет, делал кодРевью со мной, и начал мне везде предлагать то и то исправить на `статические классы`...надо ему показать переписку в понедельник(правда перевести придется).  цитирую: вот есть метод, добавь в статический класс и это тоже добавь и вот кусочек кода....‍♀️у меня в один момент голова начала кипеть, столько всего поменять(где то было интересно), соединить,ну а потом мне все это тестировать со всех сторон. ***а насчет форматирования и правда глаза режет(ctrlK ctrlD в студию), и имена переменных

Comment: @rotabor [заходите в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146289/discussion-on-answer-by-evgeniyz-------)